# Django: How to override methods

Tags: python, django

In my Django app I have to override methods sometimes. My question is if there is something like a "best practice" in how to override a method.

Example: In my project I have the following class.

```
class AuthorCreate(CreateView):
    model = Author
    form_class = AuthorForm
    template_name = 'app/create_author.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.creator = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

So here I have overridden the [`form_valid()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L55) method. It works and I think it's correct. However, is that good practice or not, e.g. I see something like this often:

```
def overridden_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #Some logic here
    pass
```

So, should have I done it this way?

```
def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            self.object.creator = self.request.user
            self.object.save()
            return super().form_valid(form)
```

So my question is basically **WHEN** I should use **WHICH** "template" for overriding methods or **WHEN** not to use some specific form. I'd be glad about some detailed/explained best practices. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

This really depends on the method you are overriding but a rule of thumb is to check the documentation for methods that you want to override. Especially things like the `save()` method on a model and others. The reason you need `*args` and `**kwargs` for some methods is not because it's a "template" but more because Django passes other arguments and keyword arguments when running the method that you might accidentally leave out if you omit `*args` and `**kwargs`.

If you look at Django's [`save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) method, you'll see that there are a ton of keyword arguments that are passed through by default.

Let's look at an example of abstract models. If you override it to be:

```
class SomeAbstractModel(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField(max_length=55)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self):
        super().save()
```

You're basically disallowing anyone who inherits this model to pass any keyword arguments to override Django's default keyword arguments on the `save()` method. In this case it would be a better practice to write:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, I would think this won't be necessary if you are very certain that you would not need this flexibility, or if anyone who might depend on your code would not need this flexibility.